# How to handle fragment back stacks using mvvmcross Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Currently I am using Showviewmodel for navigating to different pages in Navigation drawer, but I click back I am able to see all my previous pages.So is there anyway to clear all previous fragment stack using mvvmcross?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the attribute

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true)]
```

on top of each MvxActivity you dont want to save in the backstack